# How do I configure multiple sources for Data tables using require JS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am attempting to use this [data table](https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap-simple.html).
But there are multiple JS resources required and I am not sure how to configure both for `RequireJS`? I attempted to create a shim but the table is not rendering.

Below are the two files required:

```
 jquery.dataTables.min.js

 dataTables.bootstrap.min.js
```

So far I have it partially working and rendering using the following configuration:

```
require.config({

    paths: {
        jquery: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min',
        dataTable: 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min',

          // How do I create a shim for this?
        dataTableBootstrap: 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min'

    }
});
```

*Instantiate here:*

```
require(["jquery", "dataTable"], function ($) {

    $(function () {

        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
            scrollY:        '50vh',
            scrollCollapse: true,
            "scrollX": true,
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bInfo": true
        } );

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to shim for any of those. They are recognized as requirejs modules and managed their own dependencies instead of you. They all have [universal module definition](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) format. They all create themselfs as require module with define() and trying to get theirs dependency. This dependency is named and it's name is either path or name defined in `paths` requirejs configuration.

Now from those libraries I was able to find module names they require.

dataTable boostrap requires 2 dependency `["jquery","datatables.net"]`. jquery is defined well in your `paths` config but `datatables.net` is nowhere to be found because you define different name for it `dataTable`.

This means that your `dataTable` path need to be changed for `datatables.net`

```
datatables.net: 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min',
```

This way all you need to define/require as dependency is `jquery` and `dataTableBootstrap`

```
define(["jquery", "dataTableBootstrap"], function ($) {
    // code here
}
```

This should fix issue but I was not testing it though.

As for shim. It is required only for non-requirejs (non AMD) depdencenies as you need to specify theirs dependency yourself. AMD modules instead manage theirs dependency.

Comment: I am a bit confused by this line. `dataTables.bootstrap.min.js it is ["jquery","datatables.net"]`. Am I putting this in a shim but you say I do not need shim??

Comment: well you don't need to shim them just define theirs path. They are recognized by requirejs as they are requirejs modules already. Shim is usefull if you don't have requirejs module and you want to use it in requirejs modules. Your problem here is that they are managing their dependencies themself but they are looking for different name that you defined in your requirejs configuration. They are looking for module named `datatables.net` but you defined this module with name `dataTable`. different name = requirejs is not able to find it.

Comment: Okay got it!! Thank you so much for the clarity. It's working now as needed.

Comment: Sorry I probably overcomplicated my answer. I'v just edited it to make it simpler and hopefully better to understood.